# PostgreSQL: Count based on distinct entries in different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following is the schema of the txn table -

```
 ID |   SrcNO   |    DstNO    | SrcCountry | DstCountry |   Type   | 
  1       A            B            USA          UK         RECV
  2       A            B            USA          UK         RECV
  3       B            H            UK           IND        SEND  
  4       C            D            UK           GER        SEND
```

The aim is to capture the count of txns from a SrcNO/DstNo of UK to other countries. In other words, I want to group the count of txn's where UK is SrcCountry/DstCountry for any SrcNo/DstNo respectively -

```
 No |  Country  | Send | RECV 
  B      USA        0      2
  B      IND        1      0 
  B      GER        0      0  
  C      USA        0      0
  C      IND        0      0 
  C      GER        1      0
```

Remark - As there isn't any txn send/recv for B with GER and C with USA,IND we have to display the count as 0 for both cases SEND/RECV.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happened to "No" values of "C", "H", and "D"?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select country, No, sum(send) as send, sum(recv) as recv
from ((select srcCountry as country, dstNo as No, 1 as send, 0 as recv
       from t
       where dstCountry = 'UK' and type = 'SEND'
      ) union all
      (select srcCountry as country, dstNo as No, 0 as send, 1 as recv
       from t
       where dstCountry = 'UK' and type = 'RECV'
      ) union all
      (select destCountry as country, dstNo as No, 1 as send, 0 as recv
       from t
       where srcCountry = 'UK' and type = 'SEND'
      ) union all
      (select dstCountry as country, dstNo as No, 0 as send, 1 as recv
       from t
       where srcCountry = 'UK' and type = 'RECV'
      )
     ) c
group by country, no;
```

I should note that this will skip countries where all values are 0.  If you really need those, you can include extra rows in the subquery.  However, it is not clear to me what happened to, say, the rows with `No` of "H", so I'm unclear what you really want.

Comment: I don't want data corresponding to H. H is a DstNo belonging to India. My concern is SrcNo and DstNo belonging to UK.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple CTEs:

```
WITH config (c) AS (SELECT 'UK'::varchar),
countries (country) AS (
  SELECT srccountry FROM t WHERE srccountry NOT IN (SELECT c FROM config)
  UNION
  SELECT dstcountry FROM t WHERE dstcountry NOT IN (SELECT c FROM config)
),
nos (no) AS (
  SELECT srcno FROM t WHERE srccountry IN (SELECT c FROM config) AND type = 'SEND'
  UNION
  SELECT dstno FROM t WHERE dstcountry IN (SELECT c FROM config) AND type = 'RECV'
),
send (no, country, send) AS (
  SELECT srcno, dstcountry, COUNT(*)
  FROM config LEFT JOIN t ON srccountry = c
  GROUP BY srcno, dstcountry
),
recv (no, country, recv) AS (
  SELECT dstno, srccountry, COUNT(*)
  FROM config LEFT JOIN t ON dstcountry = c
  GROUP BY dstno, srccountry
)
SELECT no, country, COALESCE(send, 0) AS send, COALESCE(recv, 0) AS recv
FROM countries
CROSS JOIN nos
LEFT JOIN send USING (no, country)
LEFT JOIN recv USING (no, country);
```

- The config "table" is there only so that you don't have to change UK in different places in the query;
- The countries "table" retrieves all the countries different from UK (or whatever country you put in config);
- The nos "table" retrieves all the nos sent or received by UK;
- The send "table" counts the number of each product sent by UK (and who received it);
- The recv "table" counts the number of each product received by UK (and who sent it);
- The final query joins all these results.